# Hive External table not showing anything

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume

I am trying to learn Hive by following twitter data tutorial from the below link.
https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/

I have successfully installed and configured hadoop and hive and tested simple text file load into hive table. All working good so far.

However, even thought files existed in hdfs, external table is showing nothing.

I used the below code to create tables.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (
... 
 Columns ....
...
)
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets';
```

I think where the problem comes in is the folder structure in my hdfs ..
it's currently follows year/month/day/hour/ like below.

```
/user
  -- /flume
      -- /tweets
          -- /2015         
              -- 04        
                -- 01      
                 -- 13     
                 -- 14
                -- 02
                 -- 15
                 -- 16
```

Is there a way to set the partition correctly for this folder structure when creating external table in Hive ?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the partition to the table.

```
  ADD JAR   your-serde-jar-file-path.jar


  ALTER TABLE tweets ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datehour = 2015040113) LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets/2015/04/01/13';
```

-you have to pass  datehour and partionpath form oozie cord file.

```
 ADD JAR ${JSON_SERDE};

ALTER TABLE tweets ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datehour ${DATEHOUR}) LOCATION '${PARTITION_PATH}';
```

Please refer it
  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-schedule-recurring-hadoop-jobs-with-apache-oozie/

Comment: so what does this alter statement do ? Does that mean I need to add a partition of every hour of every day and month to table manually one by one ?

Comment: it will add the  partition to the tweets table. in that alter statement  you have to give the location of that partiton. refer it -http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions

Comment: you should schedule it  by Oozie hive-action. refer it...http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-schedule-recurring-hadoop-jobs-with-apache-oozie/

Comment: Amazing ... Oozie was the one i was going to learn next. Will try out ! Thanks !